# Is there a POSIX function to copy a file?

Tags: c, posix

Looking now through some OS functions I find that on POSIX systems you have C function calls like `unlink()` to remove files, `link()` to create hard links to files, `symlink()` to create symbolic files, `rename()` to move a file, but ... where is a function to `copy()` a file?

I know that the usual way is to just open the source file, read its contents, open a destination file and dump them there. But why can't I find any such utility function given all the previous ones?

Comment: copying a file is a rather long-running and complex operation; even where the OS has a system-library `CopyFile` function (such as Windows does), this is unlikely to be implemented as _system call_ but rather as utility function. There's several ways of creating a copy, and UN*X has never chosen to be too explicit about _how to do things_ (i.e. sell a `copy()` as the golden path to creating file copies0.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When talking about "copying a file", two semantics exist:

1. *Deep Copy* - the creation of a new file containing a copy of all data / metadata associated with the file, however the filesystem structures this
2. *Shallow Copy* - the creation of a new directory entry/file *referring to the same data* (and possible some or all of the metadata) as the source file

Windows / DOS filesystems traditionally didn't have any "shallow copy" mechanism - but UN*X always had, in the form of *hard links*.

So POSIX/UN*X has the [`link(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/link.html) system call - to establish a new reference to existing "file data" under a new name - i.e., do a *shallow copy*.

A "deep copy" system call only makes sense if there is a "fast deep copy" mechanism - for example, in cases where the underlaying filesystem implements something like deduplucation to do file-level cloning.

Otherwise, such a function would have to "degrade" (fall back to) a library implementation.

The UN*X mechanism to allow for something as filesystem-specific as this is `ioctl()`, the "kitchen sink of I/O extensibility". For an example as how to use this facility, if available, to copy files, see [this GNU coreutils post](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2011-08/msg00006.html) with an enhancement request to use file cloning on BTRFS.

Given that Windows' `CopyFile` is actually `CopyFileEx` without a callback, I strongly doubt it's really a *system call*; it's a utility function. For the [Wine Windows Emulator](http://www.winehq.org), you can check the kernel32.dll source implementation, find `CopyFileEx` in the Wine sources, [`dlls/kernel32/path.c`](http://source.winehq.org/git/wine.git/blob?f=dlls/kernel32/path.c) for an example how this *can* be done.
Disassembling / Decompiling Windows' actual `kernel.dll` is not allowed under Microsoft's licensing, so I cannot legally assert that Windows itself does the same, i.e. `CopyFile` is a userland implementation, *not a system call*.

To compare Windows and UN*X again here... not *everything* in UN*X libc is a system call, that's why the UN*X manpages distinguish between section 2 (sys calls) and section 3 (runtime library interfaces). The same is true for functions in `kernel.dll` on Windows - some of them are "direct passthrough" while others are more complex "utility functions" not implemented via a *single* system call.

Comment: Regarding the whole disassembly thing, in some (most?) authorities, it is perfectly legal to do so (even explicitly stated!). And EULAs have no legal meaning in Europe. **DISCLAIMER:** I am not a lawyer, if you want to do this, you should seek legal counsel, etc etc etc...

Comment: @TimČas: I made no claim on that - merely saying that _here_, I won't quote any disassembly of Microsoft-provided non-opensource binaries to assert this does exactly the same.

Comment: Modern `cp` on Linux uses `copy_file_range` (which was added in Linux 4.5: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/copy_file_range.2.html) to reflink the data, copy-on-write with BTRFS.  Also potentially allows NFS server-side copying.

Answer (score 18):

I tried running strace on the cp command on Linux and it actually open both files and it reads from one file and write to the other one in blocks of 32768 bytes:

```
...
stat64("log", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=352, ...}) = 0
stat64("copied", 0xbf99e1c0)              = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("log", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=352, ...}) = 0
open("copied", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_LARGEFILE, 0644) = 4
fstat64(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
read(3, "2012-04-27 22:26:55-0400 [-] Log"..., 32768) = 352
write(4, "2012-04-27 22:26:55-0400 [-] Log"..., 352) = 352
read(3, "", 32768)                      = 0
close(4)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
...
```

So yes, there is no cp syscall out there. Hope it helps you.

Comment: On a more modern Linux system, `cp` will open both input and output files, but will use `copy_file_range(3, NULL, 4, NULL, 9223372035781033984, 0) = 68`, allowing server-side copies on NFS, and reflinks on FSes like BTRFS that support it (copy-on-write where both inodes point to the same data for now, but a write to one will allocate new space, unlike a hardlink.)  So copying a huge file on BTRFS takes no time.  But `copy_file_range` is Linux, not POSIX.  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/copy_file_range.2.html POSIX `sendfile` requires that one of the fds is a pipe, unlike splice or c_f_r

Answer (score 1):

You can't find the utility function for copying a file because there isn't a need for it in the same way; it can be built out of 'spare parts'.  Functions like `unlink()` and `symlink()` can't be built in terms of other functions, whereas functions such as a hypothetical `copy_file()` can (so you must).

Given two open file streams, `f1` for reading and `f2` for writing, then you could use:

```
void fcopy(FILE *f1, FILE *f2)
{
    char            buffer[BUFSIZ];
    size_t          n;

    while ((n = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), f1)) > 0)
    {
        if (fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), n, f2) != n)
            err_syserr("write failed\n");
    }
}
```

The `err_syserr()` function is for error reporting including the string passed as an argument and the error message implied by `errno`<sup>*</sup>; it does not return.  `BUFSIZ` is defined in `<stdio.h>` but you might choose to use a bigger value.  You might prefer not to error report like that, but have the function return 0 on success and -1 on any failure.

```
int fcopy(FILE *f1, FILE *f2)
{
    char            buffer[BUFSIZ];
    size_t          n;

    while ((n = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), f1)) > 0)
    {
        if (fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), n, f2) != n)
            return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that because the function does not open the files, it does not close them either.  This means you could use it to concatenate multiple input files to a single output file, for example.  You could use a wrapper function to open a file for reading and another for writing.

<sup>*</sup> *Actually, `err_syserr()` is a function like `printf()` which takes a format string and other arguments, and then reports the error message as described and exits.*

Comment: It is interesting that you mention that you could build one out of spare parts, but then your copy version doesn't copy file attributes. New file attribute extensions related to security will be lost too, as will resource forks on platforms like macosx, so you can't actually write portable code... I don't know, it just seems like POSIX dropped the ball here...

Comment: `system("cp --preserve=all file1 file2")`

Comment: The code I show doesn't open the files, and the file open or create code would be where you deal with things like attributes. Resource forks are inherently non-portable; POSIX doesn't legislate for the behaviour of things it knows nothing about. You can look at any given platform to find platform-specific alternatives that do what you want, but they won't be portable.  Also, there are so many possible behaviours that it would be hard to design the API.  Does it copy modification times? Permissions? What if the target file already exists? Is a symlink? ACL security information?  Etc.

Comment: As others have noted, if you need more elaborate behaviour, you can invoke the system utilities that support it with `fork()` and `exec()`.  Those programs, however, also have to be coded to handle what you need — so someone has to do the work.  POSIX tends to provide a lowest common denominator so that systems can support it more easily.  (Technically, POSIX doesn't support ACLs; they were a proposed extension, but never got finalized, though most implementations hew close to the last draft of the proposed extensioin.)

Comment: This code will quietly stop on a read error. You should really be checking feof(f1) at the end of the function.

Comment: does it copy as well special files? If not, how can I copy a fifo file by preserving its content?

Comment: @snr If the file stream is open to a special file (for input or output), then the data will be read from one file (possibly a special file) to the other (possibly a special file), ultimately using the `read()` and `write()` system calls, or their close relatives. So, assuming the special file behaves sanely under read or write (as appropriate), the information will copied. What that actually means depends on the device and device drivers behind the special file, but usually that means "preserves its content". There are notable exceptions: e.g. `/dev/null`, `/dev/zero` and `/dev/random`.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX systems do not provide system calls like CopyFile function in Win32, so do not waste your time searching the `Copy_file()` function. If you do not want to reinvent the wheel, I think it is a good idea to use `fork()` to create a new process and call `execl()`. Like this:

```
execl("/bin/cp", "-p", src_file, des_file, (char *)0);
```