# Copying files from one folder to another in C Program

Tags: c, filesystems

I want to copy some files from one folder to other folder and before copying or replacing the files I want to take backup from destination folder only those file which are I am trying to copy in to source file to destination file.

This is what I want to do but is this possible in pure C-language?.

Comment: It is Possible with C.Try To Write Code and Get back if you have problem in writing specific piece of code. Do not expect Code from Some one.

Comment: It is possible to write such a program in C but it sound like a task much more suited for a scripting langue  such as Python.

Comment: Show the program what you have tried, this is not a site for asking the own question, it is site for asking the problem what you have faced.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should say on which platform you want to do that.

I'm not that familiar with Windows so what i'll be saying only applies to Linux (maybe it works on windows as well but I doubt it).

Have a look on [man opendir](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) and [man readdir](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) and those are the only things you need to do what you want (you obviously will also need to open/read/write and close but I imagine that you know that).

Answer (score 0):

There's no *native* way in C to do that. You need **platform-specific code**. The simplest way to achieve that is to use the [`system()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system) function

```
system("copy C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe D:\\");  // Windows
```

or

```
system("cp ~/myfile.txt ~/mycopiedfile.txt");  // *nix
```

But for better performance and/or more control over the result you need to call the corresponding APIs if available (like [`CopyFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfile) on Windows), or copy the file on your own by reading from source to a buffer with `fread()` then write to the destination with `fwrite()`

See [Is there a POSIX function to copy a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17666316/995714)